# How to pause macro, then do my stuff and continue/resume from where I left?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2013

I got data in one sheet form B2:ZY191, and I want to copy each row (B2:ZY2,B3:ZY3, and so on till B191:ZY191) to another workbook worksheet for analysis. Now while doing so I sometimes need to stop and mark my results in between and then continue from where I left. For example, I started the macro and it copied from B2:ZY2 to B52:ZY52 then I pause the macro & mark my results. Now I want to continue from B52:ZY52 onwards then again if I want to stop after copying data till B95:ZY95 I should be able to pause the macro, mark my result and continue from B95:ZY95 thereon. I should be able to do this as many times as I want. 
If provided with buttons like start, pause and resume would be very helpful.

Comment: You should use break points and run the Macro in F8 Mode. this is useful while debugging. Or do u mean to give the end user the ability to pause and continue? If so you should split the code into multiple procedures which can be run on click sequentially.

Comment: well I wanted something with buttons. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you could adopt the following workaround:

- choose the "sets" you want to virtually divide your data range into

  let's say:

  - set#1 = rows 1 to 20
  - set#2 = rows 21 to 30
  - ... and so on
- mark with any character in column "A" the final rows of all chosen sets

  so you'd put a "1" (or any other character other than "|I|" or "|E|" - see below) in the following cells of column "A" (i.e. the one preceding your data range):

  - A21
  - A31
  - ..., and so on

  (since your data starts at row 2 then its ith row is in worksheet row I+1)

then you put the following code in any module of your data range workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoThings()
    Dim dataRng As Range, rngToCopy As Range

    'assuming Analysis.xlsx is already open

    Set dataRng = Worksheets("BZ").Range("B2:ZY191") '<--| this is the whole data range. you can change it (both worksheet name and range address) but be sure to have a free column preceeding it
    Set rngToCopy = GetCurrentRange(dataRng) '<--| try and set the next "set" range to copy
    If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then '<--| if no "set" range has been found...inform the user and exit sub!
        MsgBox "There's an '|E|' at cell " _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & dataRng(dataRng.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(, -1).Address _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " marking data has already been entirely copied" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Remove it if you want to start anew", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With rngToCopy
        Workbooks("Analysis").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(.Address).value = .value
    End With

End Sub

Function GetCurrentRange(dataRng As Range) As Range
    Dim f As Range
    Dim iniRow As Long, endRow As Long

    With dataRng
        With .Offset(, -1)
            Set f = .Resize(, 1).Find(what:="|E|", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| look for the "all copied" mark ("|E|")
            If Not f Is Nothing Then Exit Function '<--| if "all copied" mark was there then exit function

            Set f = .Resize(, 1).Find(what:="|I|", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| look for any "initial" mark put by a preceeding sub run
            If f Is Nothing Then '<--|if there was no "initial" mark ...
                iniRow = 1 '<--| ...then assume first row as initial one
            Else
                iniRow = f.row - .Cells(1).row + 1 '<--| ... otherwise assume "marked" row as initial one
                f.ClearContents '<--| and clear it not to found it the next time
            End If

            endRow = .Cells(iniRow, 1).End(xlDown).row - .Cells(1).row + 1 '<--| set the last row as the next one with any making in column "A"
            If endRow >= .Rows.Count Then '<--| if no mark has been found...
                endRow = .Rows.Count '<--| ...set the last row as data last row...
                .Cells(endRow, 1).value = "|E|" '<--|... and put the "all copied" mark in it
            Else
                .Cells(endRow, 1).ClearContents '<--| ...otherwise clear it...
                .Cells(endRow + 1, 1).value = "|I|" '<--| ... and mark the next one as initial for a subsequent run
            End If
        End With
        Set GetCurrentRange = .Rows(iniRow).Resize(endRow - iniRow + 1) '<--| finally, set the range to be copied
    End With
End Function
```

and make it run as many times as you need: after each time it ends and you can *mark your result* and then make it run again and it'll restart form where it left

Comment: @MehulPatel: did you try this?

Comment: @MehulPatel: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Stop` and `Debug.Print` to achieve the desired results when placed within your code.  For example if you're looping through a range, add the statement of choice with an if statement:

```
for a = 1 to 150
    if a = 20 or a = 40 then
        debug.Print "The value of a is: " & a.value 'or whatever you want to see
    end if
next
```

This will print to the immediates window, or use stop to pause your code in a strategic place in the same manner.

I dont understand what you mean by buttons? They surely aren't a good idea as the code will run too fast?